# Why am I getting "Multiple actions were found ..." when I have exactly one Post action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

My `FBMessageController` has nothing but the following methods:

```
public string Get() { ... }

[ChildActionOnly]
public SendResponse Send(ComplexType msg) { ... }

[ChildActionOnly]
public SendResponse SendImage(string x, string y) { ... }

[HttpPost]
public SendResponse Post([FromBody]AnotherComplexType yyy) { ... }

public void Put(..) { ... }

public void Delete(..) { ... }
```

However, when I tried to send a request using POST to `.../api/fbMessage`,

I get the following exception:

> "Mutliple actions were found that match the request"

`WebApiConfig.Register` contains the default code:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

What is causing the error?

Comment: the exception message usually tells you which actions conflicted. check if there are any inner exceptions that give you a clue.

Comment: take a look at this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Troubleshooting Idea: Although 'Send' and 'SendImage' are not labeled 'Post', they may be communicating via Http Post - and may  have the same 'signature' as the 'Post' method.. Use Fiddler and also comment out 'Send' and 'SendImage' to see if this is the avenue to pursue.

Comment: @SRQCoder I was wondering the same thing. looking for documentation now to see if Send is one of the special names that the convention uses when selecting sctions.

Comment: @OldGeezer. you seem to be mixing Web API and MVC attribute as `System.Web.Mvc.ChildActionOnly` is an MVC attribute and not Web API

Comment: Check your bin folder and make sure you don't have another assembly in there that might map to the same route. This can happen if you renamed the assembly at some point.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs. The offending method is `Send`. I decorate it with some other Http method and it works. It won't work even if I rename it to SendXX and not decorated explictly. However, `SendImage` is fine with no decoration. I have updated my question with the parameters of `Send` and `SendImage`. I wonder if this could give a clue to the exact cause. (PS: Making `Send` private also works.)

Comment: @Nkosi Yes, I am using System.Web.Mvc.ChidActionOnly. Are you saying that this has no effect and Http requests coming in will still be able to access methods so decorated?

Comment: @OldGeezer, I don't believe that attribute has any effect on the Web API stack as they are separate code bases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you seem to have already isolated the issue, I did the following integration test to recreate your problem and help explain what is causing the error.

```
[TestClass]
public class FBMessageControllerTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task HttpClient_Should_Get_OKStatus_From_Post_To_FBMessage() {

        using (var server = new TestServer()) {

            var config = server.Configuration;
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );


            var handlerMock = new Mock<IExceptionHandler>();
            handlerMock
                .Setup(m => m.HandleAsync(It.IsAny<ExceptionHandlerContext>(), It.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>()))
                .Callback<ExceptionHandlerContext, CancellationToken>((context, token) => {
                    var innerException = context.ExceptionContext.Exception;

                    Assert.Fail(innerException.Message);
                });
            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), handlerMock.Object);



            var client = server.CreateClient();

            string url = "http://localhost/api/fbMessage";

            var body = new { body = "Hello World" };

            using (var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, body)) {
                var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode, message);
            }
        }
    }

    [Authorize]
    public class FBMessageController : ApiController {
        public string Get() {
            return null;
        }

        [System.Web.Mvc.ChildActionOnly]
        public SendResponse Send(ComplexType test) {
            return null;
        }

        [System.Web.Mvc.ChildActionOnly]
        public SendResponse SendImage(string x, string y) {
            return null;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public SendResponse Post([FromBody]AnotherComplexType body) {
            return null;
        }

        public void Put(string gbody) {
            return;
        }

        public void Delete(string body) {
            return;
        }
    }

    public class SendResponse { }
    public class ComplexType {  }
    public class AnotherComplexType {  }
}
```

Which produced the following result message:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request:
>   Send on type MiscUnitTests+FBMessageControllerTests+FBMessageController
>   Post on type MiscUnitTests+FBMessageControllerTests+FBMessageController

The above message tells you exactly what caused the problem. The framework usually tells you why you got certain errors. Sometimes you have to know where to look.

Referencing the following [Routing and Action Selection in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection), here is why you got the problem.

> here is the action selection algorithm.
>
> 1. Create a list of all actions on the controller that match the HTTP request method.
> 2. If the route dictionary has an "action" entry, remove actions whose name does not match this value.
> 3. Try to match action parameters to the URI, as follows:
>
>    - For each action, get a list of the parameters that are a simple type, where the binding gets the parameter from the URI.
>        Exclude optional parameters.
>    - From this list, try to find a match for each parameter name, either in the route dictionary or in the URI query string. Matches are
>        case insensitive and do not depend on the parameter order.
>    - Select an action where every parameter in the list has a match in the URI.
>    - If more that one action meets these criteria, pick the one with the most parameter matches.
> 4. Ignore actions with the [NonAction] attribute.
>
> Step #3 is probably the most confusing. The basic idea is that a
>   parameter can get its value either from the URI, from the request
>   body, or from a custom binding. For parameters that come from the URI,
>   we want to ensure that the URI actually contains a value for that
>   parameter, either in the path (via the route dictionary) or in the
>   query string.
>
> For example, consider the following action:
>
> ```
> public void Get(int id)
> ```
>
> The id parameter binds to the URI. Therefore, this action can only
>   match a URI that contains a value for "id", either in the route
>   dictionary or in the query string.
>
> Optional parameters are an exception, because they are optional. For
>   an optional parameter, it's OK if the binding can't get the value from
>   the URI.
>
> **Complex types are an exception for a different reason. A complex type
>   can only bind to the URI through a custom binding. But in that case,
>   the framework cannot know in advance whether the parameter would bind
>   to a particular URI. To find out, it would need to invoke the binding.
>   The goal of the selection algorithm is to select an action from the
>   static description, before invoking any bindings. Therefore, complex
>   types are excluded from the matching algorithm.**
>
> After the action is selected, all parameter bindings are invoked.
>
> Summary:
>
> - The action must match the HTTP method of the request.
> - The action name must match the "action" entry in the route dictionary, if present.
> - For every parameter of the action, if the parameter is taken from the URI, then the parameter name must be found either in the route
>     dictionary or in the URI query string. (Optional parameters and
>     parameters with complex types are excluded.)
> - Try to match the most number of parameters. The best match might be a method with no parameters.

Hope this helps you understand Why you got the “Multiple actions were found …” message.

Happy coding!!!

Comment: @Nikosi, thanks for your dedication. Pardon my slowness, but I still do not get which selection criteria caused `Send` to be another matching action. I thought if not explictly decorated, the default Http method is Get? Wouldn't that eliminate `Send` using the first criteria?  Also, my `ComplexType` is very different from `AnotherComplexType`.

Comment: `Send` and `Post` are action names that can be used interchangeably in the convention. Also the two actions both have one complex parameter types which are excluded when trying to match parameters. I'll bold the section that relates to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If HTTP method attribute is not defined specifically, default is POST. So Send() is also considered as post method and the exception occurs because more than one action were found.

You can try installing Debug Router tool to get visual understanding of how the controller and action were selected. Here's [a link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to decorate all your action with attribute like this to see if anything change

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get() { ... }

[ChildActionOnly]
public SendResponse Send(..) { ... }

[ChildActionOnly]
public SendResponse SendImage(..) { ... }

[HttpPost]
public SendResponse Post([FromBody]xxx yyy) { ... }

[HttpPut]
public void Put(..) { ... }

[HttpDelete]
public void Delete(..) { ... }
```

May be your Put and Post are conflicting somehow.